# php array with json_encode send jquery, then insert array values in input fields

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

Have such php array

```
Array
(
[Title] => Text for title  
[Description] => Text for: description.
)
```

Then from php send back to jquery with `echo json_encode($meta_back, JSON_HEX_QUOT|JSON_HEX_TAG|JSON_HEX_AMP|JSON_HEX_APOS);`

In jquery with alert see this

```
{"Title":"Text for title  ","Text for: description."}
```

then

```
$.each( [ meta_from_url ], function( title, description ) {
alert( 'title_ ' + title + ' description_ ' + description );
});
```

And with alert see

```
title_ 0 description_ {"Title":"Text for title  ","Description":"Text for: description."}
```

What is incorrect in my code? title is 0 and whole data is in description

Comment: Have you tried using JSON.parse on the return value before attempting to loop over it?

Comment: Tried with $.parseJSON( meta_from_url ); and get something like `Object..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why loop over the properties of an object? Just access them directly

```
alert( 'title_ ' + meta_from_url.Title + ' description_ ' + meta_from_url.Description );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct and is functioning properly.

```
$.each( [ meta_from_url ], function( title, description ) {
alert( 'title_ ' + title + ' description_ ' + description );
});
```

Here title is KEY and description is VALUE for the array. Your first entry has KEY value 0. Thus it is printing 0.

What you need is :

```
$.each( [ meta_from_url ], function( title, description ) {
alert( 'title_ ' + description.Title + ' description_ ' + description.Description );
});
```

Comment: hmmm, also see `title_ undefined description_ undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this

```
var data = $.parseJSON( meta_from_url );
alert( 'title_ ' + data.Title + ' description_ ' + data.Description );
```

Comment: wit alert see `title_ undefined description_ undefined`

Comment: sorry all is ok. I was missing `var meta_from_url = $.parseJSON( meta_from_url );` But in answer instead of `data` should be `meta_from_url`

Answer (score 0):

The callback of your `$.each` expects ( index, object ) as parameters. Not two strings. 
That's why `title_` is `0` (index) and `description_` is the string representation of your whole object.